# Vue should only trigger the clicked element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm on my first Vue project. I have a table with cells. When I double click a cell, I want to trigger a child component in that cell with `updated` or similar.

So far I've been doing that by sending props to it. It works. The problem is that when I double click a cell, the `updated` is triggered in all the child components. It can be triggered 100 or 1000 of times, just for a single cell to be "activated".

### Screenshot

[image]

### Code and question

This code below is far from how my project looks like, but will still show the issue. Click on a button and all the cells will react to it, not just the one clicked.

I do understand why it happends. In my child component I output data that has been changed by the parent. Then all child components react on it. However, there is no need to trigger them all when they are not active.

How can I just trigger the `updated` of the item I'm clicking on?

```js
Vue.component('v-child', {
  props: ['item', 'active'],
  updated() {
    console.log('Clicked');
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      {{ item }} {{ active }}
  </div>`
  });

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: 0,
   items: {
     first: '1',
      second: '2',
      third: '3',
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
      c: 'c'
    },
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
   click(item) {
      this.active = item;
      console.log(this.active);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <li v-for="item in items">
      <button v-on:click="click(item)">Button</button>
      <v-child :item="item" :active="active"></v-child>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<v-child ...></v-test>` is it a typo or real bug?

Comment: You say you "understand why it happends", can you explain?

Comment: @Andrey It was a typo that now have been fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @jaudo I've now added some more information about it. I hope it's a bit better now.

Comment: I see multiple ways to do what you want. 1st is move button inside child and modify it's data on click. 2nd will be not to pass `item` to `v-child` but pass if the item matches active item like `:active='active === item'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updated` is called for every child because `active` has changed, so each child needs to be rendered.

There are 2 ways to achieve what you want:

- Cause `active` to change only for the active item
- Keep your code and add some verification to check if the child is the active one (Steven Spungin solution)

Example for solution #1

```js
Vue.component('v-child', {
  props: ['item', 'active'],
  updated() {
    console.log('Clicked');
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      {{ item.value }} {{ item.count }}
  </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: 0,
    items: {
      first: {value:'1', count:0},
      second: {value:'2', count:0},
      third: {value:'3', count:0},
      a: {value:'a', count:0},
      b: {value:'b', count:0},
      c: {value:'c', count:0}
    },
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    click(item) {
      item.count++;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <button v-on:click="click(item)">Button</button>
    <v-child :item="item" :active="active"></v-child>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! 1. How can that be done? By placing the button inside the child component? That is not really an option for me because every field inside a cell should be a plugin like a textarea plugin or something else. 2. Yes, but that will be 1000 checks for each click on a large table with 100 rows.

Comment: I added code snippet for solution 1. The counter is just an example, you just need to trigger some change specific to the clicked item.

Comment: This concept did work! Instead of counters I set `active` to a boolean. I also need to set the previous active item to false, but to not loop a 1000 items, I can just keep track of the previous active row/col in data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add a watch to `active` and compare the `active` value to the `item`.

```js
Vue.component('v-child', {
  props: ['item', 'active'],
  watch: {
    active(value) {
      if (value === this.item) {
        console.log('Clicked:' + value);
      }
    }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
      {{ item }} {{ active }}
  </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    active: 0,
    items: {
      first: '1',
      second: '2',
      third: '3',
      a: 'a',
      b: 'b',
      c: 'c'
    },
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },
  methods: {
    click(item) {
      this.active = item;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <li v-for="item in items">
    <button v-on:click="click(item)">Button</button>
    <v-child :item="item" :active="active"></v-child>
  </li>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem with this is that all the components are still triggered. That is what I'm trying to prevent. The `watch` will be called 1000 times on a big table with 100 rows for example.

Comment: It seems like `watch` is faster than `updated` because watch only look at updated data and props and `updated` look at if the dom has changed. I found a better solution to my problem but at least I gave you an upvote. Thanks!